# Plugin to enable HTML tag auto-closing in Notepad++

Tags: windows, html, web-development, css, notepad++

Is there a plugin for Notepad++ that works with Windows and automatically creates closing tags/brackets when writing HTML and CSS?

For example, when writing `<ul>` it would create some `<li></li>` and `</ul>` instantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notepad++ already has an option to do that. You just need to activate it under *Settings* -> *Preferences* -> *Auto completion*

1. Check **Enable auto-completion on each input** *(optional)*
2. Check **html/xml close tag**

[image]

<sup>The screenshot is taken from Notepad++ version 6.5.1 (unicode)</sup>

Comment: this works for HTML but not CSS

Comment: How come you have such a dialog? I just installed the latest Notepad++ and I don't have the HTML option in the Preferences tab as in the picture. I need the HTML tag completion. Please what version is this?

Comment: @davidXYZ The screenshot is taken from Notepad++ version 6.5.1 (unicode)

Comment: Okay. I now see what happened. My company blocks most external websites. Every Google search result for Notepad++ download was blocked, including `notepad-plus-plus.org`. I thought I got around it when I found that I could access the Sourceforge result, however the version they have is only v5.9 (Build Time: March 2011). Oh well... Thanks. **Edit:** I was able to get the TextFX plugin and now I have the HTML auto-completion I was looking for.

Comment: @davidXYZ Notepad++ is portable. So you could install it on a flash drive at home and bring it with you. I'm glad you found another plug-in. It might be worth posting it as another answer if it fits the question

Answer (score 0):

It's not plugin, it's NP++ internal function, as answered.
Also check out **SynWrite** - also with internal autocomplete and tag auto-close for HTML, CSS. See help topic about it -

[image: Help]