# PHP editor with extras

Tags: web-development, text-editor, php, html-editor, autocomplete

I am looking for a PHP/JS/HTML/CSS editor which has autocomplete function (like IntelliJ IDEA & Eclipse).

It would be also great if it supports themes :)

Dreamweaver is too heavy for me with a lots of unuseful stuff. Something light like Notepad++ and with the autocomplete extra would be just perfect.

Comment: Notepad++ already has an autocomplete feature. You just have to turn it on in the settings. See this question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11519/6834

Comment: doesn't work well with PHP unfortunately it is not comparable with the one from eclipse

Comment: Requirements are _pretty close_ to [Cross platform JS/PHP editor software with FTP support and code hinting](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6/cross-platform-js-php-editor-software-with-ftp-support-and-code-hinting/327#327). Though not quite identical, I think you'll find some good recommendations there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to NuSphere's [PHPED](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped_features.htm).  I was looking for an IDE with a PHP debugger and found PHPEd.  In the process, I found it also supported what you're looking for.  It's feature list is impressive given it's relatively low cost.  I had also looked at using Eclipse with a PHP plugin, but, decided against that because the debugger was "kluggy" to use.  I settled on PHPEd because it provided most, if not all, of the features you would expect from a major IDE with some unexpected features as well.  For example, it also provides code profiling and unit tests.

Comment: Could you add a link and some personal experience with this tool? What makes it great? Imagine giving a personal recommendation to someone face to face. You certainly would tell the person more about the tool.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Per request, updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

**[SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/download.html)** editor is little similar to N++ but has more features. It has autocomplete for:

- HTML, CSS: built-in
- PHP: needed [**plugin SynCodeIntel**](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/syncodeintel/) (install using "Plugin Manager" item in "Tools" menu)
- JS: not tested, but maybe SynCodeIntel supports JS too
- Python: needed plugin SynJedi (install in "Plugin Manager")

PHP completion:

[image: PHP list]

It supports theming via skins and color customizing.